# WannaCry spread

Tags: network

I'm using Centos 7 as my OS. Today I got a file .wcry and because I don't know I try to open using gedit. It seems the file cannot be open. I do some digging and it will not work under Linux. However, in my network my files are store in cloud server (WD EX4100) and I using SMB service as file sharing protocol in my network. After I open this file suddenly my file storage cannot be access. My question is, is the wcry can spread to my network from what I do? or maybe just my network error? 
Thanks

Comment: Firstly, if you're aware of wcry and you have the file on your system, _why on earth_ are you trying to do _anything_ with it outside of a sandbox?

Comment: I haven't read the outbreak. Just knew couple minutes later after I open it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the current report it won't affect the Linux & Mac and targets only unpatched Windows system excluding Windows 10.
I exploits the [CVE-2017-0145](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-0145) in Microsoft Windows Vista SP2; Windows Server 2008 SP2 and R2 SP1; Windows 7 SP1; Windows 8.1; Windows Server 2012 Gold and R2; Windows RT 8.1; and Windows 10 Gold, 1511, and 1607; and Windows Server 2016.

So i guess you are not infected, although once activated It then searches the whole computer for any file with any of the following file name extensions:

> .123, .jpeg , .rb , .602 , .jpg , .rtf , .doc , .js , .sch , .3dm ,
>   .jsp , .sh , .3ds , .key , .sldm , .3g2 , .lay , .sldm , .3gp , .lay6
>   , .sldx , .7z , .ldf , .slk , .accdb , .m3u , .sln , .aes , .m4u ,
>   .snt , .ai , .max , .sql , .ARC , .mdb , .sqlite3 , .asc , .mdf ,
>   .sqlitedb , .asf , .mid , .stc , .asm , .mkv , .std , .asp , .mml ,
>   .sti , .avi , .mov , .stw , .backup , .mp3 , .suo , .bak , .mp4 , .svg
>   , .bat , .mpeg , .swf , .bmp , .mpg , .sxc , .brd , .msg , .sxd , .bz2
>   , .myd , .sxi , .c , .myi , .sxm , .cgm , .nef , .sxw , .class , .odb
>   , .tar , .cmd , .odg , .tbk , .cpp , .odp , .tgz , .crt , .ods , .tif
>   , .cs , .odt , .tiff , .csr , .onetoc2 , .txt , .csv , .ost , .uop ,
>   .db , .otg , .uot , .dbf , .otp , .vb , .dch , .ots , .vbs , .der” ,
>   .ott , .vcd , .dif , .p12 , .vdi , .dip , .PAQ , .vmdk , .djvu , .pas
>   , .vmx , .docb , .pdf , .vob , .docm , .pem , .vsd , .docx , .pfx ,
>   .vsdx , .dot , .php , .wav , .dotm , .pl , .wb2 , .dotx , .png , .wk1
>   , .dwg , .pot , .wks , .edb , .potm , .wma , .eml , .potx , .wmv ,
>   .fla , .ppam , .xlc , .flv , .pps , .xlm , .frm , .ppsm , .xls , .gif
>   , .ppsx , .xlsb , .gpg , .ppt , .xlsm , .gz , .pptm , .xlsx , .h ,
>   .pptx , .xlt , .hwp , .ps1 , .xltm , .ibd , .psd , .xltx , .iso , .pst
>   , .xlw , .jar , .rar , .zip , .java , .raw.

and encrypts all files it finds and renames them by appending `.WNCRY` to the file name. For example, if a file is named picture.jpg, the ransomware encrypts and renames the file to `picture.jpg.WNCRY`.

So you have it.

Comment: Thanks for your info. What a relieve. So to make myself clear. The virus will not work in my WD EX4100 right? since it wasn't Windows

Comment: Can you upload the file here https://www.virustotal.com/ and share the results

Comment: I already can access my cloud again seems to be network problem. So I confirm that the virus is not infecting cloud. @Vinod, Sorry I already delete the file soon after I heard about the outbreak.